# Graphic in Excel of lifetime and capacity of power plants

Tags: microsoft-excel, matlab

I have data on capacity, construction date and shutdown date of different power plants. I would like to build a graph in Excel that shows at one glance these information, i.e. in sort of a shifted histogram. That is, the rectangle for the power plant that was built in 1970 and shut down in 2000 starts in 1970 and ends in 2000 and the width of the rectangle represents its capacity.
Each type of power plant should have a different color (3 types of power plants with many plants for each type).

Do you know how this sort of graphic is called?
Do you know how to build it in Excel (or I could do it in Matlab I suppose if not possible in Excel)?

Comment: My guess would be it's just a bar graph with the difference that you want to use a variable for the width. From what I can tell this is going to be difficult with Excel without using VB but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Please supply some sample data and what you expect the graph to look like (a scanned drawing and made up data is sufficient)

Comment: Right! The colleagues below already took care of that :) Only disadvantage of their solution is that the plants' capacities intersect and are not on top of each other so that one can see the overall capacity at one glance... any ideas? I prefer Matlab to Excel VB, actually. Maybe I can use the Matlab command boxplot somehow? But how could I change the design of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played around with the idea you're suggesting, and I think i have something quite basic along the lines of what you want. But it isn't pretty.

Start a new table, with first column the date range of your data (I went for jan-90 to dec-99, for no particular reason)

Each plant needs to be its own column, and for the date range it was active, enter it's capacity. For the dates it was inactive, just enter 0.

[image: demo table]

presenting the data like this allows excel to make something like this:
[image: demo graph1]

or as a stacked graph:

[image: demo graph2]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's great that it's quite simple to do :) What I had in mind, though, is that each rectangle for each plant is drawn on top of each other so that you can see by the height of the whole plot what overall capacity was online at any given point... do you have any idea on that?

Comment: I think that should be possible, I'll add another answer.

Comment: Ahaa! You just used the "stacked graph" option in the graphics tools or how did you do it?

Comment: Yeah, just stacked graph. I wasn't exactly sure what you were looking for to start with, and I'm only just getting to grips with Excels graphs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with only 4 data points for each plant.

[image]

To make the graphs continuous, set "Show empty cells as..." to "Connect data points" in the "Source Data..." dialog box in the Chart menu.

[image]

Showing the total capacity at any time with this type of graph gets a bit trickier - you have to show the total capacity as plants come online and go offline.  Here's a way to get it done. This shows the contribution of each plant to the total capacity over time:

[image]
[image]

But @O.Allen's area graph is probably the simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an idea on how to draw each rectangle for each plant on top of each other so that you can see by the height of the whole plot what overall capacity was online at any given point?